# Atomic spectrum question?

Tags: atomic-physics

If an electron in atom absorbs a lem wave of particular energy and gets to excited state but later return to its ground state then will emitted energy = absorbed ?

Comment: Yes this can happen but also it could go down to the ground state in two or more steps

Comment: What's a 'lem wave'?